# Parition, luks and windows boot manager

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, encryption

i hope you will understand my English.

I have bought a dell xps 15 9550, I've installed ubuntu-20.04.3 64 bit with luks and lvm and then installed windows(I've shrinked the lvm and then made an ntfs partition for win).Then I've installed grub on the root partition and added the entry with easybcd. All was ok but after some problems I decided to reinstall. Windows is encrypted with veracrypt so this is the reason why i need the windows boot manager instead of grub. So now...

I made two partition, /boot and /, configured the ext4 (/) partition as "physical volume for encryption", (I'm running on legacy bios and mbr table). All is correctly installed, but I can't add the entries with easybcd. I tried with supergrubdisk and it read and start my ubuntu partition. So is installed and it run but only with supergrubdisk , with easybcd it doesn't boot it remain with a black screen with an underscore on the top left and stop.
What I tried (inside the system always starting with supergrubdisk not chroot):
-Install grub on /boot partition --it install but it doesn't boot as entry on windows boot manager
-Install grub on root partition --error saying it can't determine filesystem type
So any help?
Thanks in advance and sorry again for my English

Comment: You say /boot & /root.  I suspect you mean /boot & / root directory; as / is the root directory; but /root is the directory of the root user (it's not located in /home). You should also provide release details.

Comment: yeah / as mount point, my bad i'll edit now. Thanks

Comment: Please don't add the word "solved" to the title of your question. As you have done so, you are quite at liberty to answer your own question which is more than enough to flag that your question is answered. I've edited your question accordingly. After a short period, you will be able to mark your answer as "accepted" which is all the system requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]
I put here the solution in case someone will need that.

Using this guide ¨https://techblog.mastbroek.com/all-articles/dualboot-encrypted-windows-and-ubuntu/5/¨.

I stetted up all like previously but this time i made a larger boot partition
(1024mb). Then when veracrypt boot-loader appear, simply press esc key and it will detect grub on the /boot partition and it will start ubuntu.